# after M-x prelude-update I get error: Wrong type argument: stringp, 100

Tags: emacs-prelude

System: Linux Mint 20
Emacs version 26.3

I updated all packages with package-list-packages and then ran M-x prelude-update.
After restarting emacs with emacs --debug -init I get this error:

### (Does anyone have an idea what this "100" is?)

````
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp 100)
  expand-file-name(100 "/home/belberg/.emacs.d/")
  projectile-expand-root(100)
  projectile-verify-file(100)
  apply(projectile-verify-file 100)
  #f(compiled-function (&rest cl-x) #<bytecode 0x205cff5>)(100)
  mapcar(#f(compiled-function (&rest cl-x) #<bytecode 0x205cff5>) "debian/control")
  cl-mapcar(#f(compiled-function (&rest cl-x) #<bytecode 0x205cff5>) "debian/control")
  apply(cl-mapcar #f(compiled-function (&rest cl-x) #<bytecode 0x205cff5>) "debian/control" nil)
  cl-map(nil #f(compiled-function (&rest cl-x) #<bytecode 0x205cff5>) "debian/control")
  apply(cl-map nil #f(compiled-function (&rest cl-x) #<bytecode 0x205cff5>) "debian/control" nil)
  cl-every(projectile-verify-file "debian/control")
  projectile-verify-files("debian/control")
  #f(compiled-function (project-type-record) #<bytecode 0x1af4f89>)((debian marker-files "debian/control" project-file "debian/control" compilation-dir nil configure-command nil compile-command "debuild -uc -us" test-command nil install-command nil package-command nil run-command nil))
```
```
"Missing modules file %s" "You can get started by copying the bundled example file from sample/prelude-modules.el" expand-file-name "custom.el" delete "^[^#.].*\\.el$" "Prelude is ready to do thy bidding, Master %s!" version< "25.3" eval-after-load "enriched" #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x483f0d>) prelude-eval-after-init run-at-time ...] 8)
  load("/home/belberg/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1e0f4d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try commenting out the references to `projectile` in `core/prelude-editor.el`.  Restart emacs, then run `M-x package-list-packages`.  Type `U` when the package list has refreshed, then `x` to install the packages.  After the packages have refreshed, quit emacs, uncomment what you commented out in `core/prelude-editor.el` and restart emacs.

Comment: Thank you so much beamso!  This did the trick!  I have no idea how you figured this out? I would never have tried this.  Very happy!